# Select words with at least two different letters

Tags: java

I am using this code

```
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("\\b[ABE]+\\b").matcher(key);
```

to only get keys from a `HashMap` that contain the letters A, B or E

I am not though interested in words such as AAAAAA or EEEEE I need words with at least two different letters (in the best case, three).

Is there a way to modify the regex ? Can anyone offer insight on this?

Comment: If you only have three letters, this seems pretty straightforward to me. Check if each of the letters are present (using `String.indexOf()` - trust me, this is fast), if yes, increment a counter. Then check that counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace everything except your letters, make a Set of the result, test the Set for size.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String alphabet = "ABC";
    String totest = "BBA";

    if (args.length == 2)
    {
        alphabet = args[0];
        totest = args[1];
    }
    String cleared = totest.replaceAll ("[^" + alphabet + "]", "");
    char[] ca = cleared.toCharArray ();
    Set <Character> unique = new HashSet <Character> ();
    for (char c: ca)
        unique.add (c);
    System.out.println ("Result: " + (unique.size () > 1));
}
```

Example implementation

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more complicated regex to do it e.g.

```
(.*A.*[BE].*|.*[BE].*A.*)|(.*B.*[AE].*|.*[AE].*B.*)|(.*E.*[BA].*|.*[BA].*E.*)
```

But it's probably going to be more easy to understand to do some kind of replacement, for instance make a loop that replaces one letter at a time with '', and check the size of the new string each time - if it changes the size of the string twice, then you've got two of your desired characters. **EDIT:** actually, if you know the set of desired characters at runtime *before* you do the check, NullUserException had it right in his comment - `indexOf` or `contains` will be more efficient and probably more readable than this.

Note that if your set of desired characters is unknown at compile time (or at least pre-string-checking at runtime), the second option is preferable - if you're looking for *any* characters, just replace all occurrences of the first character in a `while(str.length > 0)` loop - the number of times it goes through the loop is the number of different characters you've got.

Answer (score -1):

Mark explicitly the repetition of desired letters, 
It would look like this :

```
  \b[ABE]{1,3}\b
```

It matches AAE, EEE, AEE but not AAAA, AAEE

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for - "...at least two different letters..."